# Business or tourism for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, france, spain

I have been trying to get a Schengen Visa for a forthcoming half business-half pleasure trip. The plan is to be in Spain for 5 days for business and head on to France for 7 days for tourism. I went to apply at the Spanish Embassy and was told to take my application to the French embassy seeing my duration of days spent in France is longer. Then, I went to the French embassy and was advised to apply at the Spanish embassy because apparently Schengen Visa prioritizes business over tourism..?

At the French embassy I explained my case and provided evidence of being asked to apply at their embassy. They replied saying that they will accept my application but will also discuss this with the Spanish embassy and if in case the Spanish embassy agrees to handle my case, my already submitted application at the French embassy will be canceled, the visa fees would be wasted and I, myself will have to apply again at the Embassy of Spain.

I am quite afraid of not making my deadline because of the inter-embassy confusion. Neither is the French embassy responsive to any of my emails / calls. What is to be done in this case?